# Can we provide priority, description of testng class fromm excel?

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse

**I want to pass test-ng priority  through excel file . 
Is there any way to do that ?**

Comment: Would you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using excel it means you are working on Keyword driven framework, not executing it as a TestNG test-cases directly or not using testNG XML.

So you cannot pass testNG priority. If you want to prioritize your test-cases, you need to create your own login like to read all the test-cases from excel at 1 go and pass some priority and create logic to execute most priority first and so on...